# iOS custom UITableView and UITableViewCell with columns (Twitter app)

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone/iPod application, and the designer used a lot of these "Twitter App Concepts" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EGFk.jpg)). As you can see, the TableView has a shadow and the cells can be split in columns (those columns are clickable).

I just need to create those columns, any idea how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prettykit library is probably a good place to start, as the library is a subclass of UITableViewCell and UINavigationController.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/prettykit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well a `UITableViewCell` is a `UIView` so in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you hit that row simply add 3 subviews to the UITableViewCell.

There is one downside to this approach though and that is if there are a lot of these "Column Cells" then it will hinder performance. You also tend to want to avoid more then 5 subviews in a `UITableViewCell`

In case you are wondering "Why can't i just add multiple cells to a Single Row?"

Good question and the reason is UITableView's `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` ([Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3a)) this takes an Index Path which is a combination of the Section Number and Row Number the Cell is in.

As it only returns a single cel, it's impossible to return multiple cells (unless you write a custom implementation), but you can return a cell with multiple subviews that has a unique identifier ;)

1. [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class Reference
2. [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) Class Reference

Edit: The library that danielbeard linked looks to be a good implementation to use.

Answer (score 0):

*Use your own subclass of UITableViewCell instead of UItableviewcell. And Customise your cell as you want.*